# Android: show image in mTabHost

Tags: android, android-fragments

Presently  i have dynamic values `Ipsum.stringHashMap.get(name)[0]` which shows the file name i.e `abs_crunch1.png`. But i want to display image on the content instead of `abs_crunch1.png`, How can i achieve this?

```
 public void updateArticleView(int position,String name) {    
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(Ipsum.stringHashMap.get(name)[0]).setIndicator("Steps"),
                TabFragment1.class, null); 
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(Ipsum.stringHashMap.get(name)[1]).setIndicator("Info"),
                TabFragment2.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec(Ipsum.stringHashMap.get(name)[2]).setIndicator("Warnings"),
                TabFragment3.class, null); 
        mCurrentPosition = position;
    }
```

Screen Output

[image]

Comment: Sincerely, you should switch to `TabLayout`

Comment: @NikolaDespotoski But my class already extending Fragments. If i  use `TabLayout` then i need to extend `AppCompatActivity` then the existing functionality will not work which requires `Fragments` class to extend